How to deploy a spacy ner model and fastapi
I have a custom spacy ner model ad fastapi that works fine when run in the local machine. But when I tried to deploy it in railway, it crashes and produces error like it can't access the model in spacy.load() even if it's in the same directory.
Process SpawnProcess-1:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap

self.run()

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run

self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/_subprocess.py", line 78, in subprocess_started

target(sockets=sockets)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run

return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run

return runner.run(main)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run

return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve

await self._serve(sockets)

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve

config.load()

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 433, in load

self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string

module = importlib.import_module(module_str)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/root/.nix-profile/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "/app/main.py", line 146, in <module>

nlp = spacy.load(model_dir)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 51, in load

return util.load_model(

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 469, in load_model

return load_model_from_path(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 535, in load_model_from_path

meta = get_model_meta(model_path)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 929, in get_model_meta

return load_meta(model_path / "meta.json")

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 890, in load_meta

meta = srsly.read_json(path)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/srsly/_json_api.py", line 53, in read_json

return ujson.load(f)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: Expected object or value

i also tried making the custom ner model as a package, but it still didn't work. What should be the correct setup to deploy a spacy ner model and fastapi?
